# Nanoframework esp32 Can't no set fix ip address

Tags: wifi, esp32, nanoframework

went I am running following code. the IP-adresse is not 192.168.1.99 but 192.168.1.45.
I hav change the IP-adresse, but it is still 192.168.1.45
Help and thanks.

```
namespace WeatherStation
```

{
public class Program
{
private static readonly string _mySsid = "network";
private static readonly string _myPassword = "password";
private static readonly IPConfiguration _configuration = new IPConfiguration("192.168.1.99", "255.255.255.0", "192.168.1.1");

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Starting weather statiom!");

        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for network up and IP address...");

            CancellationTokenSource cs = new(60000);

            bool success = WifiNetworkHelper.ConnectFixAddress(_mySsid, _myPassword, _configuration, requiresDateTime: true, token: cs.Token);

            if (!success)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Can't get a proper IP address and DateTime, error: {WifiNetworkHelper.Status}.");
                if (WifiNetworkHelper.HelperException != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {WifiNetworkHelper.HelperException}");
                }
                return;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Network is up and running");
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{ex}");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does the IP address gets updated to the new one if you reboot the ESP32?

Comment: It starts with 192.168.1.73 and now it is 192.168.1.45. Have followed tried with another new route, same problem.

Comment: Looks like an issue with storing it an using it. Better raise an issue in the project GitHub.

Comment: actually there's already an open issue about this, you can follow it to know when it's fixed: https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/1087